# Fragstats input data for whole study area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, fragstats

I have a land cover map covering an area of 1560 square km. I am interested in landscape fragmentation analysis using Fragstats. But I am confused about input data for the whole study area. I do not have problem on data preparation but problem about whole study area. I am not sure about how can I use whole study area as input data. Could anyone please let me clear about how can I use my whole study area for the analysis?

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with?  The more detail that you provide us, the easier it is for us to help troubleshoot. Are you using this with GIS software? If so, what version? Please update your question to provide us more information.

Comment: Thanks !vI have seen a couple of tutorials on input data as specific cell area of the study area as; grid (50m/50m)>buffer>negative cell value for the buffer edge>positive cell value for the inside landuse> converting raster or ASCCII. I want landscape metrics to the whole study area of 1560 sqm, not only single grid. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2. Is it possible to get landscape metrics from the whole study area? If possible then how to prepare input data for the whole study area?

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS 10.2 is your problem. According to the [Fragstats information page](http://www.umass.edu/landeco/research/fragstats/faq/fragstats_faq.html#Q8), you cannot use Fragstats with ArcGIS newer than 10.0:

> Version 4.2 should be compatible with all versions of ArcGIS 10.0 and
>   earlier, but it will not work with ArcGIS 10.1 or later.